# Will MySql work fine with Node Js framework?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new in web development, I don't much know about Databases. I want to know, will MySql work well with Node Js?

If anyone has experience with MySql and Node Js please share with me.

Thank You.

Comment: Yes. Use the [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) package and its [Promise wrapper](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it does work well with nodejs.

You can use [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) package if you want to write plain sql code or you can use [sequelize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize) to work with relational databases in a nosql way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL with NodeJS without any problems. Like you said you are new in web development so you can use `sequelize` library for database operations. `sequelize` is a library that facilitates database operations.